# Nginx - return based on geolocation

Tags: nginx

This is my config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name test.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/test.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/test.com/test.com.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;


      if ($geoip2_data_country_iso_code = "FR") {
        return 301 https://test.com/fr$request_uri;
      }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to redirect user from France to /fr page (keeping whole original pathname). This of course does not work right now. The error is "too many redirects". Any other user should just use the standard test.com page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more simple solution will be to use [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
if ($geoip2_data_country_iso_code = "FR") {
    rewrite ^(?!/fr/) /fr$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This rewrite rule will trigger only if current request URI is not already starting with the `/fr/` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everything is redirected **including the URLs starting with `/fr`**, e.g.

1. `https://example.com/something`
2. `301 https://example.com/fr/something`
3. `301 https://example.com/fr/fr/something`
4. `301 https://example.com/fr/fr/fr/something`
5. `301 https://example.com/fr/fr/fr/fr/something`
6. ...

You should not put that `if` inside a `location` either, as [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Nginx does not support multiple if conditions inside each other, nor `&&` syntax.

You could try to circumvent this with something like this:

```
set $redir "";

if ($geoip2_data_country_iso_code = "FR") {
    set $redir "fr";
}

if ($request_uri ~ ^/fr/) {
    set $redir "";
}

if ($redir = "fr") {
    return 301 https://example.com/fr$request_uri;
}
```